# Can I create a domain-wide singleton service in Weblogic?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

We currently have a clustered Weblogic setup for several pieces of our application to reach the usual guarantees in load balancing, fail-over, and so on. Recently, we've added a singleton service implementing weblogic.cluster...SingletonService, which does the job it was designed for, but it seems not the job we require of it. In the current setup there are multiple clusters under the same domain that would need to access the singleton service, but it seems that this does not work.

How can we set up a singleton service domain-wide, that is, for multiple clusters concurrently?

Sanity test: is our observation that the Weblogic SingletonService can not be used domain-wide correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states

> "A singleton service is a service running on a managed server that is
>   available on only one member of a cluster at a time"

so yes, your sanity test is ok.

There isn't any domain-wide singleton functionality in WebLogic. I can imagine some workarounds:

- Using JMX to inspect which servers are running, retrieving the server name from System properties and running your logic only if the first running managed server name and the current server name matches.
- Setup a domain wide Coherence cluster, and compare the local member with the oldest member of the cluster and use that to decide which server is the leader and runs your logic.
- Setup some horrible semaphore logic using the JNDI tree, which is a domain wide resource.